# How to highlight words when using a Word add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, add-in, office-addins, word-addins

I'm currently working on a Word add-in. In simple words, the tool searches for words in a dictionary and then proposes a definition. I would like to highlight all the words where for the add-in has a definition. The problem is when using the "highlight"-option of the Word API, it overwrites highlights of the user and makes changes to the "undo"-stack.

I think this is possible as I've saw an example of the Grammarly Word add-in:
[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLVHu.png)

Does anyone has an idea how to realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible using Office JS APIs.

The screenshot displays the capability of the Grammarly VSTO based add-in, which is able to display the proofing marks you see on the document. This capability is not yet available on Office JS.